# Random number isn't quite random

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

This function selects a random quote from the text file quotes.txt (each quote is delimited by a @) and displays it in the quotes div, such as `<div class="quotes">quote shown here</div>` on each page load.

But why does it sometimes skip a quote and show nothing in the `<div>`?

```
$.get('quotes.txt', function(data) {
    var quotes = data.split("\@");
    var idx = Math.floor(quotes.length * Math.random());
    $('.quotes').html(quotes[idx]);
});
```

Is it a problem with the random generator (which from my reading seems to be not very random)? Is there a way to make it only random select from a set number of quotes, i.e. 50? Is there a better way - maybe php - to generate a random number between 1 and 50?

quotes.txt looks like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit@ 
Fusce tincidunt, ante ut scelerisque@ 
Mauris lacinia, magna sed auctor pellentesque, diam nisl rutrum ligula@ 
Etiam tempor elementum augue, vitae cursus eros laoreet@ 
Donec imperdiet ullamcorper pharetra@
```

**Edit 4/27/11**  I ended up using a different function that doesn't have issues with showing blank lines. quotes.html is structured this way:

```
<div class="quote">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
<div class="quote">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</div>
```

Function:

```
$('div#quotescontainer').load('quotes.html',function(){
var $quotes = $(this).find('div.quote');
var n = $quotes.length;
var random = Math.floor( Math.random()*n );
$quotes.hide().eq(random).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Check the contents of the `quotes` array in a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a different function that doesn't have issues with showing blank lines. quotes.html is structured this way:

```
<div class="quote">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</div>
<div class="quote">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</div>
```

Function:

```
$('div#quotescontainer').load('quotes.html',function(){
var $quotes = $(this).find('div.quote');
var n = $quotes.length;
var random = Math.floor( Math.random()*n );
$quotes.hide().eq(random).fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 8):

After splitting the file on `@`, the *last* item in `quotes` will probably be an empty string, since you've got a `@` before the newline at the end of the file.

As for the perceived "randomness" of the random number generator, there's probably no problem here. Humans are notoriously bad at detecting whether a sequence is random or not.

Comment: Yep. That's probably it! Good pick

Comment: Well, I am only human :) I removed the trailing spaces - my mistake - and the last @, but no luck. I again got blank lines, after 17, 6 and 24 page loads. How can the delimiter be fixed so I don't get blank lines?

Comment: Well, you could use `\n` (newline) as the delimiter, since your text file is already broken into one quote per line. However, text files normally end with a final `\n`, and the `.split()` method will give you one extra empty entry at the end. What you could do is filter the result of `.split()` to remove any empty entries, before choosing one to display.

Comment: Thanks, but I found another function that doesn't suffer from blank lines. Edited above.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should remove the at sign (@) at the end of your quotes.txt, because it will create an empty string in quotes array variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a jQuery function, but rather a general JavaScript function. At least the code to create the random number. You are correct though that it is not very random. I ran into this issue, and found help on this [blog post](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/random/) that helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason you may be getting blanks is that your array has a trailing blank.  If the file ends in @, and you are splitting on @, the last item will be a blank string.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove empty items from the array

```
 var quotes = data.split("\@").filter(function(itm){return !!itm});
```